# Repeated values in an arraylist

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

In my `recyclerviewAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` method I'm trying to get data and preparing a list of Names. Here `dataList` is a list of type `Options` that has some attributes and a list of type `getProductOptionValueItemList`. As the names I'm trying to get are in a list inside of `Options` so I have to loop through to get them.
Loop run correctly according to the number of items But The problem is `item.getName()` return the same value all the time even though I'm call `list.get(index);` method.

**Note:** the value i'm getting is the first element. My Code

```
    final Options data = dataList.get(position);

    holder.optionsNameTV.setText(data.getName());
    final List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.getProductOptionValueItemList().size(); i++) {
        ProductOptionValueItem item = data.getProductOptionValueItemList().get(i);
        Log.e("Option", " option name = "+ item.getName());
        options.add(item.getName());
    }
```

Comment: just debug and see if the `data.getProductOptionValueItemList().get(i)` return the correct values while cycling the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check the `data.getProductOptionValueItemList()` ? 
It may have all the elements the same, and therefore `item.getName()` appears returning the same value.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo. I was pass `index` of the outer `array` while parsing JSON data. Now with the corresponding `index`(nested index) it adds the correct values to the list of object and `getProductOptionValueItemList` returns correct values now.